# Changing localhost to a domain name

Tags: php, dns, web, connection, localhost

The following i have is the domain name, password and server. How could I alter the codes. Because everytime it loads the site it shows the error "Unable to select database". Please help me with my codes :(

[image: Domain]

[[image: Mysql{2]]

**dbConfig.php**

```
   <?php  
   $dbhost = 'localhost';
   $dbusername = 'root';
   $dbpassword = '';
   $dbname = 'calendarevent';
   $db = new mysqli($dbhost, $dbusername, $dbpassword, $dbname);
   if ($db->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $db->connect_error);
    }
   ?>
```

Comment: The DB is `calendarevent` or the hyphenated one?

Answer (score 1):

Replace localhost with the value from server on domain image.

Replace root with username value from domain image.

Where you see empty single quotes near password in the code, use the password from the domain image.

Replace calendarevent with cl41-... From the database image.

Comment: <?php
$dbhost = '79.170.**.**';
$dbusername = 'cl41-s1events';
$dbpassword = '****';
$dbname = 'cl41-s1events';
$db = new mysqli($dbhost, $dbusername, $dbpassword, $dbname);
if ($db->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $db->connect_error);
}
?>

Still not running with these codes

Answer (score 0):

```
    <?php  
      $dbhost = '<PUT YOUR SERVER NAME  [LIKE 79.170.44. some thing ] >';
      $dbusername = 'Username ';
   $dbpassword = 'your password';
   $dbname = 'There is no db name like [calendarevent] check youur db name';
   $db = new mysqli($dbhost, $dbusername, $dbpassword, $dbname);
   if ($db->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $db->connect_error);
    }
   ?>
```